# Netbeans/tmcbeans - how to change and confirm UTF-8 (mac os x)?

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, utf-8

I'm taking my first java course and it's mandatory for files to have UTF-8 encoding.

I *think* I have changed it. Followed what others have recommended and added "-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to "netbeans_default_options=" in file "netbeans.conf" located in ...Netbeans\etc with BBEdit.

If it matters I'm using tmcbeans version of netbeans (for another course on MOOC).

How can I confirm that it's now in UTF-8 encoding?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you trying to read and write to files using UTF-8 in your code?

Comment: No yet. I'm only setting up the environment now. We may read and write to files later in the course.

It's in Swedish so that's probably why they wan't UTF-8 enabled(?) since we have special chars (å, ä, ö).